# VHDL frequency shifting, two exact and close frequencies

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to create two precise frequencies at the 100 MHz range which are just a few kHz apart. A [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) isn't is a solution since it can't multiply by such big values.

The only solution I came up with is XOR two frequencies to add them. However this creates other unwanted frequencies which can only be filtered with external components.

How can I do it?

Comment: Useful search term : DDS, or Direct Digital Synthesis.

Comment: Could you add what clocks you have avialable, and what the acceptable jitter is?

Comment: What is your target architecture?

Comment: I'm using the altera DE1, and I'm trying to achieve a simple FSK transmitter, the XOR but its BW is more about 20MHz+-

Answer (score 0):

The only method I can think of are to apply the techniques that are used to build "Time To Digital Converters", i.e., [FPGA Based High Resolution Time to Digital Converter](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-007-1864-7_5). This would allow you to create FPGA based oscillators at nearly any speed, at the cost of hardware resources.

If you plan to use this in a production environment, however, you have to deal with the influence of temperature and vdd on the resulting frequencies. I know that there are FPGA based, temperature compensated circuits for just this purpose, but I guess you'll have to dig rather deep into the matter.